# Testing NACL application on previous Chromebook version

Tags: google-nativeclient, google-chrome-os, chromebook, chromium-os

I want to run chrome os application on the previous version of Chromebook.
Please let me know the process to fall back to the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generally supported method for downgrading the OS by design.

The best you can get is look at older recovery images published in the [recovery.conf](https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/recovery.conf) file.  It has links for different devices and versions.  You can install them on a USB stick and run recovery on the device.